# Need ideas on some better glass washers

Tags: cleaning, glass

I have been using a sponge to clean my drinking glasses.

My sponge and hand can not reach the bottom of the glass.

Is there something that works better?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Instead of cleaning the glasses with sponge, you can use a brush to clean them. The handle means the cleaning part is further from your hand, and should be able to reach the bottom of the glass. Some brushes might be too wide to fir in, but smaller ones are available

Comment: @Weather Vane No problem. Based on past experience, the brushes I have used don't do a good job of cleaning. Sorry, I am a bit of a perfectionist.

Answer (score 4):

A **microfibre cloth** cleans very well, because of the tiny hooks all over it. In the first picture I have put one corner into the glass. In the second picture I have screwed it around so it is tight in the glass.

The pictures show a dry cloth, but obviously you'll need to immerse  in soap suds. And twist in the opposite direction too, scrubbing the glass with a bit of pressure.

The cloth needs to be big enough to leave some of it to hold. This one is about 60 x 40 cm.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Iced tea stains my glasses. To clean, I put a damp melamine foam in the damp glass and then use a narrow brush or wooden spoon to twist the sponge around. This technique would work with an ordinary sponge.

Answer (score 1):

While never using one myself, I know there is dish cleaning sponge with handle, [found one in Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SNR5P84), for example:

[image]

As far as I can tell, it's ordinary sponge, just with handle letting you reach into glasses.

Comment: I wondered about that, but the narrowness of the glass and the angle of the sponge, suggest that if the device will fit into the glass at all, it won't reach into the bottom 'corner' of the glass. It might clean the centre of its bottom area, and its sides from an inch or two above the bottom (if rotated in the glass).

Comment: @WeatherVane well that might be the best one can get, hence why I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I usually something resembling baby bottle scrubbers. That's what they're designed for after all, cleaning a narrow container that you can't reach the bottom of.

Answer (score 0):

You can just **push the sponge in (abrasive side first) with a regular dishwashing brush**, then rotate it. Narrower-than-usual ones that can reach deep into narrow glasses are available:
[image]

Alternatively you could **soak the glass in soapy liquid for a while** (I usually put some dishwashing soap in, then fill up with water and leave in the sink until I start doing all the dishes). Any buildup at the bottom will loosen or outright dissolve, making the job much easier with a regular dishwashing brush. Pushing down (slightly sideways) and rotating should do it.

Finally, for particularly narrow glasses (there are some really fancy craft beer glasses for example, also champagne flutes etc) you can use a **bottle brush with a soft sponge at the tip**:

[image]